# How can I send directshow's graphedit output to FFMPEG?

Tags: ffmpeg, directshow, h.264, graphedit

I need to take an output from a directshow filter and use it as input to ffmpeg. Basically i will capture a video and compress it (x264 dshow filter, it needs to be hardware accelerated), and then mux it (TS) using ffmpeg. I couldn't find a TS muxer filter for ffmpeg, so i figured this would be the solution.

So, how would I send the output of graphedit to ffmpeg?

Answer (score 3):

DirectShow filter output is a non-deterministic sequence of calls on its output pins. This cannot be sent to FFmpeg. Also, there is no such thing as output of graphedit. You should be starting with input options of FFmpeg, file and non-file, and then trying to find out if you can produce this output from DirectShow filter/graph or hosting application.